# Start Activity with navigation from second fragment

Tags: android, kotlin

I have an Activity with navigation graph. The navigation graph have start destination:

```
app:startDestination="@id/loginFragment"
```

I have some case when the activity starts not to show login fragment but jump to connectFragment. So I implemented it like so:

```
val jumpToConnection = intent.getBooleanExtra("CONNECTION",false)
    if (jumpToConnection) {
        findNavController(this, R.id.navHostFragmentLogin).navigate(R.id.connectFragment)
        findNavController(this, R.id.navHostFragmentLogin).popBackStack(R.id.connectFragment,false)
    }
```

It jumps to connectFragment as intended, but when clicking back it still goes to loginFragment. Altho I cleared everything from the stack.

Comment: I previously tried the same thing for a login action. Its easier to navigate to clear an activity rather than a fragment in the stack. put the connectFragment in another activity

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following idea : Set the startDestination according your logic:

This is the nav_graph_login.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/nav_graph_login"
app:startDestination="@id/welcomeFragment">

    <fragment
    android:id="@+id/connectFragment"
    android:name="......">
    <action
        android:id="@+id/action_connectFragment_to_loginFragment"
        app:destination="@id/loginFragment"/>
</fragment>

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/loginFragment">

</fragment>
</navigation>
```

This is the login activity xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_login_container"
    android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:defaultNavHost="true">

</fragment>
```

And Finally, the login activity class where you should setup the start destination of the nav graph:

```
class LoginActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

......

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login)

    val jumpToConnection = intent.getBooleanExtra("CONNECTION",false)
    initNavigationConfiguration(jumpToConnection)
}

private fun initNavigationConfiguration(jumpToConnection: Boolean){
    val fragment : Fragment? = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_login_container)

    if(fragment != null){
        val navHostFragment = fragment as NavHostFragment
        val graphInflater = fragment.navController.navInflater
        val navGraph = graphInflater.inflate(R.navigation.nav_graph_login)
        val navController = navHostFragment.navController
        val destination = if (jumpToConnection) R.id.connectFragment else R.id.loginFragment
        navGraph.startDestination = destination
        navController.graph = navGraph
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When trying to navigate, instead of passing the fragment destination, just use an **action**.

For instance, **in your nav_graph**, add an **action** from loginFragment to connectFragment and add **popUpToInclusive = true**.

```
 <fragment
        android:id="@+id/loginFragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/loginFragment"
        android:name="packagename.LoginFragment"
        android:label="LoginFragment">
        <action
            app:popUpToInclusive="true"
            android:id="@+id/action_loginFragment_to_connectFragment"
            app:destination="@id/connectFragment" />
</fragment>
```

Answer (score 0):

> It jumps to connectFragment as intended, but when clicking back it still goes to loginFragment. Altho I cleared everything from the stack.

So your goal is not to back to the LoginFragment, right?

In your Navigation resource file (design view), click on the action line, and add the LoginFragment to the `popUpTo` field, and check the "inclusive" option.

- "popUpTo" means pop up these fragments until reaches "xxxFragment", if check "inclusive" then this "xxxFragment" will also be popped up.